# AJAX is successfully posting variables which are not visible in $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

been scratching my head for hours on this one,
I have the below JQuery code that watches for a change in the select with the name of "CategoryID".  It then posts the value of the "CategoryID" select to a PHP processor script which queries MySQL for the sub categorys and returns the updated options and populates the "SubCategoryID" select.

In the PHP processor script if I var_dump($_POST) at the top of the script I get an empty POST array.  I've also tried dumping the $_REQUEST but still empty print_r() gives the same empty array

However the script runs fine and retrieves the correct data from the db and populates the web page.
I can even change the script and save the "CategoryID" to the DB and it populates it with the correct value...
As a relative nubee to JS for my own understanding how is this possible.

I have looked at some of the other questions posted but none of them give a solution

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  $('select[name="CategoryID"]').change(function() {
    var selectedCategoryID = $('select[name="CategoryID"] option:selected').val();
    var selectedSubCategoryID = $('select[name="SubCategoryID"] option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",      
      url: '/../_JQuery/PHPProcessorScript.php',
      data: { CategoryID : selectedCategoryID, SubCategoryID : selectedSubCategoryID },
      cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
      $("select[name=SubCategoryID]").html(data);
    })
  })
})
```

PHP Processor script

```
var_dump($_POST); exit; // Returns an empty array with no ajax values
```

// If I remove exit the script returns the  expected result so the ajax values are being parsed somehow...
$_POST['CategoryID'] = trim($_POST['CategoryID']);
    $_POST['SubCategoryID'] = trim($_POST['SubCategoryID']);

```
if (empty($_POST['CategoryID'])) {
    print '<option value="">select a category first</option>';
}

if (!empty($_POST['CategoryID'])) {
    if (ctype_digit($_POST['CategoryID'])) {
        if (strlen($_POST['CategoryID']) <= 11) {
            $DBConnection = new database_connector();
            $PS1SQL = 'SELECT
                        ID,
                        Description
                       FROM db_table
                       WHERE
                        CategoryID = :CategoryID';
            $Statement = $DBConnection->Prepare($PS1SQL);
            $Statement->bindParam(':CategoryID', $_POST['CategoryID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $Statement->Execute();
            if ($PS1RS = $Statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $PS1RS = array_merge(array(000 => array('ID' => 0, 'Description' => 'choose a sub category')), $PS1RS);
                foreach ($PS1RS as $Key => $SubCategory) {
                    if ($_POST['CategoryID'] == $SubCategory['ID']) {
                        $SubCategoryList .= "<option value=\"$SubCategory[ID]\" selected=\"true\">$SubCategory[Description]</option>\n";
                    } else{
                        $SubCategoryList .= "<option value=\"$SubCategory[ID]\">$SubCategory[Description]</option>\n";
                    }
                }
                print $SubCategoryList;
            } else {
                print '<option value="" selected="true">Oops! no sub categorys available</option>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "*if I var_dump($_POST) at the top of the script*", are you reading this in the browser network tab?

Comment: Do you get the right values from the js?  (selectedCategoryID and selectedSubCategoryID). If you just do an alert(selectedCategoryID) after those two declarations. Do you get the expected value then? I believe it should be select[name="CategoryID"] and not select[name="CategoryID"] option:selected when fetching the values?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Both of those are valid ways of getting the selected value.

Comment: @El_Vanja - Ok. Thanks! But it is still important for the OP to get the expected value in the javascript :-)

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using the browser to view the PHP script output.  I've also changed the first var and removed the option:selected... however still no joy

Comment: @PHPAddict —  El_Vanja specifically asked about the **browser network tab**. When you said "the browser" do you mean the network tab? Or do you mean the viewport?

Comment: @PHPAddict I should have been explicit - I'm talking about the browser's developer console network tab. There you can see each request and check any output made by your PHP script when called by AJAX.

Comment: Yes I was looking in the network tab.  Output is below.
However I know this is working fine as the PHP script does actually work fetching the correct data from the DB it's just that I can't do a var_dump on the $_POST within the php script to see the variable values from ajax, which just returns an empty array.

<option value="" selected="true">Oops! no sub categorys available</option>array(2) {
  ["CategoryID"]=>
  &string(1) "7"
  ["SubCategoryID"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: @PHPAddict - Can you please update your question and describe what you're viewing when doing a var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: Hi, updated my post and the return from var dump is array(0) { }